# Find the sum of these definite integrals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification

[image]

(Ignore the pencil scrawls in the image, they're not by me).

This question was asked on a Singapore Facebook page supporting parents of kids taking O levels (that's age range 15 to 16). Basic calculus is taught in this course, but I found this question a little too challenging to be pegged at that level - at least the way I did it, so I wanted to ask if I'm missing a much easier approach. I also didn't need one particular piece of given info (the intermediate point $(4,7)$) so I'm left wondering if I am completely on the wrong track here. Anyway, here's the question in words, paraphrased.

You're given a sketch of a function $y = f(x)$ that's continuous, monotonic and concave upwards over the part of the domain of interest. You're told it passes through points $P(3,2);Q(4,7);R(6,9)$. You're asked to evaluate $\displaystyle \int_3^6 ydx + \int_2^9 xdy$.

Here's how I did it:

$\int_3^6 ydx + \int_2^9 xdy \\ = \int_3^6 ydx + \int_3^6 x\frac{dy}{dx}dx \\ = \int_3^6 (y + x\frac{dy}{dx}) dx \\ = \int_3^6 \frac{d}{dx} (xy) dx \\ = \int_6^{54} d(xy) \\ = 48$

Would be grateful for a critique or alternative solution. Thank you.

Comment: The integrals given are the area between the axes minus a rectangle,  so it suffices to calculate the area left =6*9-2*3=48

Comment: The area between the graph and the relevant axe,  sorry.

Comment: See for example the proof without words [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions#Statement_of_the_theorem).

Comment: I thought of the rectangle thing too, but I'm having a hard time getting $\int _2^9 xdy = \int _3^6 xy'dx$. Probably something stupidly obvious I'm not getting..

Comment: I do not know why the Q point is given....

Comment: @AlvinLepik Change of bounds with chain rule. I'm careful to use the Leibniz notation in these cases to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @dmtri Indeed, point $Q$ is not needed or used. What *is* used, however, is that the function must be invertible, which is probably assumed from the drawing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you did it is the standard approach, but the problem becomes much simpler if you think what the integrals given represent. The first integral represents the area covered by the function from  $P$ to $R$ with respect to the $x$-axis, while the second integral represents the area covered between the same points, wrt the $y$-axis.

Hence the addition of the integrals represents the difference in area of two rectangles with edges along axes.

Let the perpendicular from $P$ be called $A$ and $B$ on $x$- and $y$-axis respectively, and those from $R$ be $C$ and $D$, then the given sum of integrals represents:
$$ar(DRCO)-ar(BPAO)=9\cdot 6-3\cdot 2=48$$

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense, and it will appeal to those with more geometric insight. But what of the point $(4,7)$?

Comment: That is quite irrelevant. But the monotonocity condition is important

Comment: I agree monotonicity is important but giving a single intermediate point is not sufficient to establish that. So specifying point $Q$ is neither necessary nor sufficient.

Comment: That's why I said that $Q$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks, I agree.

Answer (score 5):

The first integral equals the pink area, the second one the blue one.

You just need to calculate a sum (or a difference, depending on an approach) of areas of two rectangles.

[image]